# Write image to SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, .net, sql

[image]

I have a button on a form application which is supposed to write an image to a SQL Server database which has been selected using `OpenFileDialog`.

What I am trying to accomplish is to tailor this code to write the selected image to a SQL Server Compact Edition that I have set up, the db is called `TestImage.sdf` and the table is called `test-table`. Currently when I click the store button I get the

> Cannot locate SQL server error

My code:

```
private void updatedata() 
{
   //use filestream object to read the image.
   //read to the full length of image to a byte array.
   //add this byte as an oracle parameter and insert it into database. 
   try     
   {
       //proceed only when the image has a valid path        
       if (imagename != "")    
       { 
         FileStream fs;
         fs = new FileStream(@imagename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
         //a byte array to read the image
         byte[] picbyte = new byte[fs.Length];     
         fs.Read(picbyte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));  
         fs.Close();
         //open the database using odp.net and insert the data  
         string connstr = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestImage; 
                            Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa";  

         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr); 
         conn.Open();  
         string query; 
         query = "insert into test_table(id_image,pic) values(" +
         textBox1.Text + "," + " @pic)";   
         SqlParameter picparameter = new SqlParameter(); 
         picparameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;   
         picparameter.ParameterName = "pic"; 
         picparameter.Value = picbyte;                
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);  
         cmd.Parameters.Add(picparameter);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         MessageBox.Show("Image Added");  
         cmd.Dispose();  
         conn.Close();
         conn.Dispose();
         Connection();
       }
   }   
   catch (Exception ex)     
   { 
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Compact Edition requires its own set of ADO.NET classes to operate.

You cannot use the classes used for SQL Server like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` etc, but you should use the corresponding `SqlCeConnection`, `SqlCeCommand` etc....

```
using  System.Data.SqlServerCe;

private void updatedata() 
{
     try     
     {
         if (imagename != "")    
         { 
            FileStream fs;
            byte[] picbyte;
            using(fs = new FileStream(@imagename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                //a byte array to read the image
                picbyte = new byte[fs.Length];     
                fs.Read(picbyte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));  
            }
            string connstr = @"Data Source=.\TestImage.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"
            string query = "insert into test_table(id_image,pic) " + 
                           "values(@id, @pic)";   
             using(SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connstr))
             using(SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn))
             {
                conn.Open();  
                SqlCeParameter picparameter = new SqlCeParameter(); 
                picparameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;   
                picparameter.ParameterName = "pic"; 
                picparameter.Value = picbyte;                
                cmd.Parameters.Add(picparameter);
                SqlCeParameter idparameter = new SqlCeParameter(); 
                idparameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;   
                idparameter.ParameterName = "id"; 
                idparameter.Value = textBox1.Text;                
                cmd.Parameters.Add(idparameter);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Image Added");  
             }
        }   
     }
      .....
```

I have modified the connection string to add the filename of the database you want to work with (supposing it is in the same directory of your application) and adapted at the standard text used by SQL Server CE.

Then I have added the appropriate [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to ensure the correct disposal of the connection and the command.

As the last thing, I have added the parameter also for the `id_image` field  (note that if this field is an Identity column you should not try to insert anything here)

Comment: I swapped my code for yours and got "The name 'picbyte' does not exist in the current context" any ideas where ive gone wrong?

Comment: Oh, yes the variable is declared inside an using statement and so it is not visible outside of it. need to move out

Comment: Added byte[] picbyte = new byte[fs.Length]; below Conn.Open(); and now when I attempt to load a .jpg I get a message "Cannot access a closed file"

Comment: have copied your edit above however, now im getting "An SqlCeParameter with ParameterName 'id' is not contained by this SqlCeParameterCollection."

Comment: Again fixed adding the name for the second parameter, sorry but I can't test that code now

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing `TestImage.sdf` in your connection string?

connection string should be

```
string connstr = @"Data Source=TestImage.sdf;Initial Catalog=TestImage; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa";
```

EDIT:
Also please note that SQL Server CE has limit ~8kB per row so the image has to be very small.

For bitmaps (of course you can load other image formats into bitmap) smaller than 200x200 I used following code

```
public static byte[] GetBytesFromBmp(Bitmap bmp)
{
            //initialize quality array
            Int64[] qual = { 100L, 90L, 80L, 70L, 60L, 50L, 40L, 30L, 20L, 10L };
            ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            var myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
            var encParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            int qualindex = 0;

            byte[] ret;
            do
            {
                //generate for selected quality
                var param = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, qual[qualindex]);
                qualindex++;
                encParameters.Param[0] = param;

                var str = new MemoryStream();
                bmp.Save(str, jpgEncoder, encParameters);
                ret = str.ToArray();

            } while (ret.Length > 7900 && qualindex < 8); //lower quality and check if the size doesn't exceeded SQL Server CE limitations

            return ret;
}
```